# How to create a 2-D numpy array from 1-D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2])
```

I want to make `n`-copies of both the elements in a 2-D numpy array, for example

```
B=[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]] # 4 copies of each element of A into a separate array
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and then reshape -

```
np.repeat(A,4).reshape(-1,4)
```

That `reshape(-1,4)` basically keeps `4` number of columns and the `-1` specifies it to compute the number of rows based on the total size of the array to be reshaped. Thus, for the given sample since `np.repeat(A,4).size` is `8`, it assigns `8/4 = 2` as the number of rows. So, it reshapes `np.repeat(A,4)` into a `2D` array of shape `(2,4)`.

Or use `np.repeat` after extending `A` to `2D` with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
np.repeat(A[:,None],4,axis=1)
```

Or use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) on extended version -

```
np.tile(A[:,None],4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply it with another array containing `1`s:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A=np.array([1,2])
>>> A[:, np.newaxis] * np.ones(4, int)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

or if a **read-only copy** is sufficient you need you can also use [`broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) (very, very fast operation):

```
>>> np.broadcast_to(A[:, None], [A.shape[0], 4])
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix multiplication with a (properly shaped) array of 1s and then transpose the final array.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2])

n = 4
B = np.ones((n, 1))
out = (A*B).T
```

You could also use `np.vstack` and then transpose the array.

```
out = np.vstack((A,)*n).T
```